# How to use FlinkKafkaConsumer to parse key separately <K,V> instead of <T>

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming

From what I can tell, with Flink's AVRO deserialization, you can create a stream of Avro-objects and that's fine, but there seems to be an issue, where Flink's kafka consumer only creates streams of single object:
`FlinkKafkaConsumerBase<T>` as opposed to your default Kafka API with its KafkaConsumer.

In my case both Key and Value are separate AVRO-schema-compliant objects and merging their schemas might be a nightmare...

Additionally it seems that with Flink API I can't retrieve ConsumerRecord information?...

Comment: It's just an additional info just loosely related to this question for anyone who would try to do it themselves:
Flink's AVRO serialization API is not compliant with kafka-avro-serialization, as the latter includes magic byte=0 and schema version int (byte[5]) into byte[] contents as prefix.

Flinks' default AvroSerializer is not compatible with it, as it tries to parse the message received from kafka directly, passing also that metadata to the deserializers, usually resulting in OutOfBoundException or an empty object T instance if one's 'lucky'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Flink Kafka Consumer, there is a constructor:

```
public FlinkKafkaConsumer(String topic, KeyedDeserializationSchema<T> deserializer, Properties props) {
    this(Collections.singletonList(topic), deserializer, props);
}
```

The second parameter - `KeyedDeserializationSchema` is used to deserialise Kafka record. It includes message key, message value, offset, topic, etc. So you can implement your own type named `MyKafkaRecord` as T with Avro key and Avro value in it. Then pass `MyKafkaRecord` as `T` to your implementation of `KeyedDeserializationSchema`. Refer to `TypeInformationKeyValueSerializationSchema` as an example.

E.g. Reading extra info from Kafka:

```
class KafkaRecord<K, V> {
  private K key;
  private V value;
  private long offset;
  private int partition;
  private String topic;

  ...
}

class MySchema<K, V> implements KeyedDeserializationSchema<KafkaRecord<K, V>> {
  KafkaRecord<K, V> deserialize(byte[] messageKey, byte[] message, String topic, int partition, long offset) {
    KafkaRecord<K, V> rec = new KafkaRecord<>();
    rec.key = KEY_DESERIaLISER.deserialize(messageKey);
    rec.value = ...;
    rec.topic = topic;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to retain kafka metadata using this information (partition, offset, timestamp)?

From what I can tell, it creates tuple(K,V), resulting with API like FlinkKafkaConsumerBase<Tuple2<K,V>>, still discarding that metadata.
Anyway, thanks for the initial answer :)

Comment: Yes you can :) `TypeInformationKeyValueSerializationSchema` is just an example for the implementation to get the key and value from Kafka. I updated the answer to include the sample retrieving extra info.